# How to modify CSS rules without adding style attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I'm a newbie to Javascript and I am trying to implement a functionality to an existing project. I want to modify the CSS rules of an html element such that I will enlarge and restore the video window. When I select the element from Chrome Developer Tools I see the following properties:

```
element.style {

}

#plug-in-container.visible {
   height: 335px;
   width: 470px;
   margin-top: -147px;
   top: 50%;
   margin-left: -229px;
   left: 50%;
}
```

I use the following code to enlarge the video:

```
$('.visible').css( {
    height: '700px',
    width: '1000px',
    'margin-top': '-350px',
    top: '50%',
    'margin-left': '-480px',
    left: '50%'
} );
```

After this, I expect the values of **#plug-in-container.visible** to change but instead of that, I see the same values as strikethrough and I see that the **element.style** is updated:

```
element.style {
   height: 700px;
   width: 1000px;
   margin-top: -350px;
   top: 50%;
   margin-left: -480px;
   left: 50%;
}
```

When I dynamically look at the html element, I see that an element **style** is created with values height, width etc. I don't want style to be created or updated, but I want to update **#plug-in-container.visible**, because that would be much safer in the conditions where I want to resize the video window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define another CSS rule on cascade with at least the same specificity of the previous one (or higher, e.g.)

```
#plug-in-container.visible.enlarged {
   height: 700px;
   width: 1000px;
   margin-top: -350px;
   margin-left: -480px;
}
```

and then just add the new class using

```
$('.visible').addClass('enlarged');
```

so, as a further benefit, you also keep the css off from the javascript.

Of course you can use this approach as long as the values you need to update are fixed and not dinamically evaluated by javascript (in that case an inline style change is necessary)

Answer (score 1):

What you see is "styles stack" if i can call it that. It shows you all rules that modify dom element. Strikethrough means that some other rule overwrites that rule.

You are using jQuery to edit css, so all styles you use in that call will appear on element itself. You can't edit CSS rules from javascript as far as I know.

How exactly would it be "safer" to edit class instead of style?

Comment: Style adds an inline style which will override all styles in the stylesheet. This might cause problems if you're using media queries or similar.

Comment: The problem was; I was using **$('.visible').css** to change the properties but that was adding a style property on my html element. When I close the video, I set it as invisible. However, in this case, even if I set it as invisible, it would still show a black box after I close the window because of the still existing style property. And since there are just too many cases where my window might close, it's not practical to go and remove the style element where appropriate. Fabrizio Calderan's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically how it works, you can't update the CSS style in another way, unless you inject another stylesheet.

So this is the intended behaviour.

When you use `$(element).css()`, you update the css for those elements, you don't edit the CSS class. That's why it gets added to the inline style attribute of that element.

Answer (score 0):

The [paris](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16277351/638546)'s question asked:

> but I want to update #plug-in-container.visible

... and [@MMM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277446/638546) replied:

> you can't update the CSS style in another way, unless you inject another stylesheet

Actually, you can. The following line modifies `padding-top` value from `20px` to `300px` on the third rule in the second stylesheet of the document:

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[2].style.paddingTop = '300px'
```

... given `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="foo.css"
  <link type="text/css" href="style.css">
<head>
<body><h1>Bar</h1></body>
</html>
```

... and `style.css`:

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
body { color: black; }
h1 { color: gray; padding-top: 20px; }
```

Therefore, regardless the practicality for the original problem, if `#plug-in-container.visible` is the first rule of the first stylesheet of the document, the styles `width`, `height` etc can be modified by:

```
var s = document.styleSheet[0].cssRules[0].style
s.height = '700px'
s.width = '1000px'
s.marginTop: '-350px'
s.marginLeft: '-480px'
```

See also MDN docs for [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet).